# File path specification in .qrc and accessing the files from the c++ code

Tags: qt, resources, image, qgraphicsview, scene

When i have this code and copy manually i.png to binary file destination

```
scene = new QGraphicsScene(this);
QPixmap pixm(qApp->applicationDirPath() + "/i.png");
scene->addPixmap(pixm);
ui->graphicsView->setScene(scene);
```

Image shows exactly as i want. Now i created resource file images.qrc. Path is set to / and contains only one file i.png. But when i change code to:

```
scene = new QGraphicsScene(this);
QPixmap pixm(":/images/i.png");
scene->addPixmap(pixm);
ui->graphicsView->setScene(scene);
```

GraphicsView remains empty. Why?

There is images.qrc

```
<RCC>
    <qresource prefix="/">
        <file>i.png</file>
    </qresource>
</RCC>
```

Comment: Show us your `.qrc` file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`":/images/i.png"` assumes that the prefix is `images`. Rather use

```
 QPixmap pixm(":/i.png");
```

Comment: LOL it does work. It was first thig i was trying... I had file with long name so it was propably typo. THX

Answer (score 2):

In order to specify the location of :/images/i.png, I'd expect the resource file to look more like this: -

```
<RCC>
<qresource prefix="/images">
    <file alias="i">images/i.png</file>
</qresource>
</RCC>
```